# How to do a document.write to load a script without overwriting the whole page

Tags: javascript, load

I am executing this code in my browser (chrome) through the url bar.

```
document.write('<script src=http://example.com/example.js></script>')
```

When that is executed on a page, it overwrites it and places:`<script src=http://example.com/example.js></script>` as the source code of the page and then launches the .js script. My question is, is it possible to launch that .js script without overwriting the entire page with a small amount of code? If so how?

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner no it is not a duplicate, i cannot use jquery and i want very short code.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the script element in javascript during the body's onload handler, and then append the script element you created to the document.

Comment: I know how to do that, but it's too long, i want something very short.

Comment: @Tom Make it into a function and call it

Comment: @Tom how is that long..? It's literally two lines, not counting the opening and closing script tag. I'm not sure if it'll work, but it's most certainly not long.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner It's easy to do the talk, i want to see the walk.

Comment: @Tom `var script = document.createElement("script"); script.src = "some url"; document.body.appendChild(script);`. And like I said, it can be put into a function that all you end up using is something like `addScript("some url");`

Comment: @Ian why doesn't `<body onload=var script = document.createElement("script"); script.src = "http://www.example.com/test.js"; document.body.appendChild(script)>` work?

Comment: @Tom You don't seem to be using quotes. Try using `<body onload='var script = document.createElement("script"); script.src = "some url"; this.appendChild(script);'>`. Although I'd advise against using inline event handlers. It could be extracted and put into `<script> window.onload = function () { /* HERE */ }; </script>`

Comment: @Ian could we not use quotes some other way without using string.fromcharcode?

Comment: @Ian I'm referring to quotes within the actual code, excluding the first and last quotes.